# In rails, How to broadcast single notification to multiple users and maintain the read/unread status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications, status, actioncable

I am broadcasting a single notification(which is either created by admin or created automatically based on user action) to either user channel or vendor channel based on notification type. I have notification table of following fields:
user_id, status(read, unread), notification_type(user_alert, vendor_alert, new_order, new_question) and detail.

When the notification_type is vendor_alert or user_alert which is created by admin, the user_id field becomes null and notification gets broadcasted to user channel or vendor channel. But if notification type is new_order or any other, user_id is set to recipient id and gets broadcasted to notification channel of that user

I have an api to read a single notification and change the notification status(read,unread) which is working fine on all notification types except user alert and vendor alert. In this case, how to track the notification status based on user. I am stuck because there is a single record of that notification.

Comment: Sounds like you could separate out your notifications table and have the read/unread flag in a notification status table. That way, you can have one status per user all linked to a single notification row.